# iso simulator does not load ios

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

When I run my application it builds successfully, but I can't run it on iOS simulator.

The problem I expect is not iOS simulator doesn't run at all. It runs, but there's nothing happen after. It just blank and there's no errors in console. So, how I understand it it's kinda does not start operating system (not switched on comparing to real device)

It seems like I do something completely wrong (and I feel it should be something really simple, some basic knowledge). I quite new to xCode and never used iOS simulator before.

So, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Clean your project and derived data folder, restart Xcode/simulator. If still not work, restart your computer/laptop.

Comment: what I try wasn't just one project - I tried a number of them and recreated the same project number of times. What I started with is ionic framework. Can't it be related to that?

Comment: Firstly, try to run an empty project with single view only. If it works problem is surely not from your Xcode.

Comment: But it's not - I'm tried to run ionic project. After no success I just created empty project with single view (and recreated it several times with different options) with the same result. I tried to add some components (e.g. web view, buttons) - the same. Comparing to my experience with adb (android emulator) it looks like emulated device is just switched off, but maybe I just don't know how it works ...

Answer (score 0):

Go to ProjectName next to run button in Xcode and choose edit scheme.

Go to Run -> Info -> Launch -> Select Automatically.

Check this:

[image]